# Linked picture is blurred in Excel for Mac

Tags: ms-office

When I copy a linked picture in Excel for Mac (v16 via 365 subscription) the linked image is far larger and blurred.  How do I ensure the linked picture is the same size and quality as the original?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please see [ask] for important info on asking questions here.  What version of macos and Excel/Office are you using?  How are you obtaining and pasting the picture?

Comment: You can click on the image.  Round and boxed corners should appear. Drag to make smaller.  Doing so may reduce the blur.

Comment: @historystamp - resizing the image makes no difference, it's still blurred

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it seems like the office suite (Excel included) automatically compresses the image. You'd have to just insert the original image. There may be a workaround for this but I haven't been able to solve it yet. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.